# Autocomplete box returns list of objects

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-ui

I have problem to display an input autocomplete text box correctly. The autocomplete content are blank rows. The debug console displays the contents are a list of {object object}. How do I parse or stringfy the object list? I tried to response($.map(JSON.parse(data), function (item) {} and it does not work. Help!

```
controller
    public JsonResult GetDegree_Autocomplete(string searchTerm)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var Degrees = (from a in _context.Degrees
                          where a.Active == true && a.Degree.Contains(searchTerm)
                          orderby a.AreaId, a.Degree
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Value = a.DegreeId.ToString(),
                              Text = a.Degree
                          });

            return Json(Degrees);
        }
View:
```

```
 <div class="ui-widget" style="width:400px;">

        <label for="Degree">Search Degrees</label>
        <input type="text" id="NDegree" name="Degree" />
  </div>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Degree").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDegree_Autocomplete")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchTerm: $("#Degree").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(data));
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Text }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: function () { }
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: doesn't seem like you'd want SelectList items here.  Just return a simple list of strings.. Construct a list (I use <UL> with <LI>'s as the options) and append it to your input field.  (add it just below...)  Though I think jQuery's autocomplete ui function will do that part for you?

Comment: You are right. I don't need that List<SelectListItem> list in the controller. But it still does not work if I return Degrees.ToList().

Comment: I think for the "source:" part you can just use the URL to your controller... so ...source:  URL_TO_GetDegree_Autocomplete  (No need for the ajax call, it will get the response... though I've not used jQuery UI before, so...)  You may also need degrees.toList() before json'ing it.  Also seems like you just need a list of degrees.name? or one of the fields there...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The  return { label: item.Text } should be lower case  return { label: item.text}.